# Upgrade from Angular 8 to 17 , error : HookWebpackError: ENOENT: no such file or directory , .... caused by plugins in Compilation.hooks.processAssets

Tags: javascript, angular, soap

I recently upgraded my application from angular 8 to Angular 17, also I upgraded many of the other libraries, I have attached the screenshot. Now, I am not able to serve the application.

Problems I faced during the upgrade:
`ngx-soap` does not work with Angular 17, I have used 'soap' (a different library) to mitigate the issues and now I am not getting any error related to `ngx-soap`.

**error**
[webpack-dev-middleware] HookWebpackError: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir at makeWebpackError 
.
.
.
-- inner error --
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir at Object.readdirSync 
.
.
.
caused by plugins in Compilation.hooks.processAssets
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir at Object.readdirSync

.
.
.

**package.json** [package.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RoRGE.png)
{
"name": "unified-message-viewer",
"version": "0.0.0",
"scripts": {
"ng": "ng",
"start": "ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port 4200 --disable-host-check --proxy-config proxy.config.json --base-href /UnifiedMessageViewer/",
"build": "ng build --base-href /UnifiedMessageViewer/",
"build:prod": "ng build --prod --base-href /UnifiedMessageViewer/ && npm run create-zip",
"test": "ng test",
"test:coverage": "ng test --code-coverage",
"test-single-run:coverage": "ng test --watch=false --code-coverage",
"lint": "ng lint",
"e2e": "ng e2e",
"storybook": "start-storybook -p 6006",
"build-storybook": "build-storybook",
"create-zip": "copy zip-util\iis-config\web.config dist\UnifiedMessageViewer\web.config && copy upload-util\receiver.ashx dist\UnifiedMessageViewer\receiver.ashx && del dist\UnifiedMessageViewer.zip  && node zip-util/create-zip.js"
},
"private": true,
"dependencies": {
"@angular/animations": "~17.2.2",
"@angular/common": "~17.2.2",
"@angular/compiler": "~17.2.2",
"@angular/core": "~17.2.2",
"@angular/forms": "~17.2.2",
"@angular/platform-browser": "~17.2.2",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~17.2.2",
"@angular/router": "~17.2.2",
"@biesbjerg/ngx-translate-extract": "^7.0.4",
"@biesbjerg/ngx-translate-extract-marker": "^1.0.0",
"@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^6.5.1",
"@ngx-translate/core": "^15.0.0",
"@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^8.0.0",
"@progress/kendo-angular-buttons": "^15.1.0",
"@progress/kendo-angular-common": "^15.1.0",
"@progress/kendo-angular-dateinputs": "^15.1.0",
"@progress/kendo-angular-dialog": "^15.1.0",
"@progress/kendo-angular-dropdowns": "^15.1.0",
"@progress/kendo-angular-excel-export": "^15.1.0",
"@progress/kendo-angular-grid": "^15.1.0",
"@progress/kendo-angular-icons": "^15.1.0",
"@progress/kendo-angular-inputs": "^15.1.0",
"@progress/kendo-angular-intl": "^15.1.0",
"@progress/kendo-angular-l10n": "^15.1.0",
"@progress/kendo-angular-label": "^15.1.0",
"@progress/kendo-angular-layout": "^15.1.0",
"@progress/kendo-angular-navigation": "^15.1.0",
"@progress/kendo-angular-pdf-export": "^15.1.0",
"@progress/kendo-angular-popup": "^15.1.0",
"@progress/kendo-angular-progressbar": "^15.1.0",
"@progress/kendo-angular-tooltip": "^15.1.0",
"@progress/kendo-angular-treeview": "^15.1.0",
"@progress/kendo-angular-upload": "^15.1.0",
"@progress/kendo-angular-utils": "^15.1.0",
"@progress/kendo-data-query": "^1.7.0",
"@progress/kendo-drawing": "^1.19.0",
"@progress/kendo-licensing": "^1.3.5",
"@progress/kendo-theme-default": "^7.2.0",
"crypto-js": "^4.2.0",
"fast-xml-parser": "^4.3.5",
"lodash": "^4.17.21",
"moment": "^2.30.1",
"rxjs": "~7.8.1",
"soap": "^1.0.0",
"tslib": "^2.6.2",
"zone.js": "~0.14.4"
},
"devDependencies": {
"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~17.2.1",
"@angular/cli": "~17.2.1",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "~17.2.2",
"@angular/language-service": "~17.2.2",
"@babel/core": "^7.23.9",
"@storybook/addon-actions": "7.6.17",
"@storybook/addon-links": "7.6.17",
"@storybook/addon-notes": "5.3.21",
"@storybook/addons": "7.6.17",
"@storybook/angular": "7.6.17",
"@types/jasmine": "~5.1.4",
"@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.13",
"@types/node": "^20.11.20",
"archiver": "^6.0.1",
"babel-loader": "^9.1.3",
"codelyzer": "^6.0.2",
"husky": "^9.0.11",
"jasmine-core": "~5.1.2",
"jasmine-spec-reporter": "~7.0.0",
"karma": "~6.4.2",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.2.0",
"karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.3",
"karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
"karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^2.1.0",
"node-sass": "^9.0.0",
"protractor": "~7.0.0",
"ts-node": "~10.9.2",
"tslint": "~5.20.1",
"typedoc": "^0.25.8",
"typescript": "~5.3.3"
}
}

I have followed through all the suggestions that I can get, but nothing is working out. Also, should I upgrade sequentially like from 8 to 9 then from 9 to 10 , 10 to 11 and so on as I upgraded directly from 8 to 17. Or is there a way to clear the serve error.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).